# Android reads certificate file

Tags: android

I really need an expert to help me. Thanks! I write a program to read a certificate file from assets and send it by socket.

However, the below line doesnt work:

`"X509Certificate clientcert=(X509Certificate)of.generateCertificate(in)"`

I am confused. The whole program is as follow:

```
private Socket client = null;
private Button button;
private FileInputStream fis = null;

private ObjectOutputStream out = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Thread (new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client = new Socket("192.168.1.186", 4444);
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

                        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                        InputStream in;
                        in = assetManager.open("client.crt");

                        CertificateFactory of = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

                        X509Certificate clientcert = (X509Certificate) of.generateCertificate(in);  

                        out.writeObject(clientcert);

                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please Try the Following Way to Read the Certificate as Follows:

```
CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("path")));
```

Comment: Your suggestion can be implemented in normal java program. But in Android, I open the certificate file by AssetManager and load it in InputStream. I am confused why I cannot generate certificate file by using inputstream.

Comment: Please follow the following link to as thats have the code to load the certificate from Assets :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829488/loading-x509certificate-from-assets-filename-public-key-is-not-correct